# PHP error handling- Undefined offset

Tags: php, error-handling, apache2

I've checked my apache error logs, and I see multiple messages like this:

```
client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 143
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 143
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 143
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 8 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 143
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 142
[Tue Dec 31 00:17:48 2013] [error] [client 108.162.246.190] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 143
```

And code around 142-143 lines looks like this (the actual 142-143 lines are implode ones):

```
    if ($nuorodoshut != NULL)
        {
            foreach ($nuorodoshut as $key => $nuorodahut) 
            {   
            $keywords = explode(' ', $qsvarus);
            $title[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $title[$key]);
            $infoo[$key] = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $infoo[$key]);
            echo '<tr><td><h3>';
            echo str_replace('<a href="/', '<a href="/host/', $nuorodahut->innertext) . '</h3>';
            echo $aprasymashut[$key]->innertext . '<br>';

            }
}
```

I just can't handle this error. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are telling you that there's no `$title[$key]` and `$infoo[$key]` when `$key` is `5` - `9`. If these two arrays should have all the same indexes as `$nuorodoshut`, then something is wrong in the creation of the arrays.

If it's OK that they shouldn't have these elements, you need to check this before you try using the values, e.g.

```
$title[$key] = isset($title[$key]) ? preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $title[$key]) : '';
$infoo[$key] = isset($infoo[$key]) ? preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $keywords).')\b(?![^<]*[>])/i', '<b>$0</b>', $infoo[$key]) : '';
```